# WPF Telerik :Remove Vertical Column on left side of the gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

As you see there is a while vertical column in the left side of this `DataGridView`:

[image]

How can I remove this parts of the teleriks's `DataGridView` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Xaml declaration of the RadGridView, you have to set :

```
RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
```

You can find more infos [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/rows/customizing-rows.html)